# ajax post failed 500 error (to django view)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I have a form with 2 fields, mobile phone number and a SMS verification code. The idea is once you enter both you submit the form via AJAX, if successful it goes somewhere else, if not it returns an error message. The reason I didn't just straight-up used the default form submit is because I wanted the page to stay put in case there's an error.

Also, not sure if this is relevant info, but I have the same form submitted into 2 different URLs via ajax, one for the SMS sending, one to submit the entire form.

OK here's the code, I took out all the formatting HTML just to make it shorter.

**TEMPLATE** - the form. The `{{ form.phone }}` is the phone number input, the `{{ form.verification }}` is the SMS verification. Also the `{% url 'login_view' %}` is the url to the view I'm posting below.

```
<form id="form_login" action = {% url 'login_view' %} method = "POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.phone }}
    {{ form.verification}} 
    <button type="button" id="btn_SendSMS" class="btn btn-primary tall_button">get SMS</button>
    <input type="submit" id="btn_login_submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary full_width_btn">
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var form = $("#form_login");        

    form.submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax ({
        async: true,
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
          if (response['status'] == 'success') {
            window.location.replace(response['redirect']);
          }
          else {
            alert(response['stage']);
            siteNotification(response['error-message']);
          }
        },
        error: function(response) {          
          alert('AJAX post failed... ' + response['stage'])
        }
      });    
    });
  });
```

**VIEW**

```
class LoginView(View):    
    FormClass = LoginForm
    response_template = 'login.html'
    redirect_url_login = '/login'
    redirect_url_customer = '/customer'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        JSONresponse = {}
        JSONresponse['stage'] = '1. entered view'

        form = self.FormClass(request.POST)

        JSONresponse['status'] = 'failed'
        JSONresponse['redirect'] = self.redirect_url_customer       

        if has_logged_in(request):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.redirect_url_customer)
        else:
            if not request.is_ajax():
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.redirect_url_login)
            else:
                JSONresponse['stage'] = '2. before form data binding'                

                if form.is_valid():
                    JSONresponse['stage'] = '3. form is valid'
                    user = authenticate(phone = str(form.cleaned_data['phone']).strip(), password = str(form.cleaned_data['verification']).strip())
                    login(request, user)
                    JSONresponse['status'] = 'success'
                    #return HttpResponseRedirect(self.redirect_url_customer)
                else:
                    JSONresponse['stage'] = '4. form is not valid'
                    JSONresponse['error-message'] = ''
                    for e in form.errors:
                        JSONresponse['error-message'] += e + ': ' + form.errors[e] + '<br>'

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(JSONresponse), content_type="application/json")
```

So I tried debugging this myself by trying to figure out where the code has reached inside the view with a ton of these `JSONresponse['stage']` assignments. If the form is completely blank and I hit submit, it reaches "4. form is not valid", which is right, at least it's evaluating the form, and it gives me the right form validation errors.

However, if I type in say a couple of random letters into the input fields and submit, it just gives me a 500 error (that's what shows up in Chrome's console) and the message is "AJAX post failed... undefined". Which means it has reached the `error` portion of the javascript, but the fact that the `JSONresponse['stage']` at the end is "undefined" means it really didn't get anywhere in the view.

What is going on here?? Also would welcome better ways to debug these things, I put in a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace();` in the view at the beginning at got a "BdbQuit" error.... have no idea what's going on there either.

**EDIT**

When I do "manage.py runserver" and replicate the error, this is what shows up in the console: [07/Sep/2015 21:34:27] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 10511. That's it, no additional information.

Comment: Full traceback please.

Comment: @Gocht sorry I'm a newbie, not really sure what that means... here's what Chrome's console shows for the 500 error, I'm amending it in the question. is this what you mean?

Comment: The full error log you get in console, where you are running your django dev server.

Comment: I meant python console.

Comment: @Gocht oh you mean when I do "manage.py runserver"? I will try that, since I don't have a local environment set up I'm purely testing this on the server side with uwsgi. I'll set up a local environment and let you know.

Comment: Setting up a local env is a must for django and pretty much everything else. Don't try new stuff on a live serve. Secondly you should ideally be testing this with known inputs using the django test client.

Comment: I will guess, give this a try: `from django.http import JsonResponse` and use it instead of `HttpResponse` as follow `return JsonResponse(JSONResponse)`.

Comment: @Gocht I set up a local environment, replicated the error, the only thing it showed up was this line: " [07/Sep/2015 21:34:27] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 10511". Not sure how helpful that is....

Comment: @Gocht the `JsonResponse` thing didn't work, exact same error.

Comment: @reedvoid Try accessing to `/login/` in a new tab/window to see more details. Do you have [django-debug-toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.2/installation.html) installed?

Comment: I think I fixed the problem, had to do with how I was iterating through the form errors. It was a list and I treated it as a single string, which was causing errors when there were more than 1 item in the list. Thanks for the advice on the local environment!!